# QGIS - Exporting a raster layer without smearing individual rasters (so you can zoom)

Tags: qgis, raster, print-composer, scale, resolution

I've been working with a raster map in QGIS (a shape file made up from squares) and now I'm trying to export it. I want to create an overview map for Germany that allows some magnification to look at individual rasters of 1km². My problem is that QGIS is sort of smearing the individual squares, smoothing the edges.

[image: "Smoothed Raster edges"]

It also looks like this after exporting it even on 1200 DPI. If I set the scale of the map to a very small scale this doesn't occur, but obviously I don't want it to occur at all.

How can this be done?

Edit: Export Settings:
[image]

I've reset it down to see if that changes anything, but it also happens on 3k DPI.

Edit2: This is how it looks in a pdf:
[image]

As you can see now we have sharp edges (still no squares) and the squares are also missaligned.

Comment: Please provide a screenshot of your export settings.

Comment: Added the settings, but we basically tried all possible settings expcept for saving as world-file already.

Comment: That's not the whole export settings. E.g. it doesn't tell, which data type you're exporting to.

Comment: That's all. We tried to export to .png and .pdf unless you mean the specific settings for pdf or image?

Comment: `.png` will always be pixelated, since it is a raster format. If you export to `.pdf` and check the "export as vector" box, your shape data (aka vector data) will be exported as vectors.

Comment: It also doesn't work in pdf. It's not pixelated anymore, instead we've got sharp edged octagons instead of squares. (They're also misspositioned for some reason)

Comment: How many segements do you buffers have? Can you provide data examples?

Comment: Going in a different direction than the other comments here, you say your raster is (has been converted to?) a "shape file of squares". I guess that means it has been vectorized. Are you absolutely sure the individual features(=converted raster pixels) are indeed squares, and perfectly aligned? Ways to check include zooming in and using the vertex edit tool (so you see vertices), modifying the layer symbology to show vertices and edges of the polygons, and copying individual features and pasting into a text editor (as WKT or GeoJson) and making sure they're squares.

Comment: There is a default Advanced Options setting to Simplify geometries to reduce output file size in the PDF Export Options dialog box.  You  would want to uncheck that.

Comment: Already tried that, but I found the solution. You need to increase the size of the print. In our case we switched from A4 to A0 and now it works perfectly fine on 300 DPI.

Answer (score 1):

Alright, found the solution. We needed to increase the size of the print page in the print-composer. When we changed the size from A4 to A0 we got rid of the weird pixellated shapes.

The resulting picture is insanely large as a png, but as a pdf we got something like 4.5mb which is acceptable enough.